# Clear Transparent Background for QWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, transparency, paint

I have a widget as on overlay for another widget. The transparency works fine, as long as I don't clear the background of the overlay.

[image: Overlay still transparent]

But I have to clear the widget to acutalize the displayed "effects". I tried to solve the inital problem (the background getting the default color) like described in [20848594](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20848594/erasing-painted-areas-from-translucent-widgets-in-qt), but except changing the color to black it had no effect...

[image: After "Clearing"]

Has anyone an idea why the widget which should be transparent does not display the underlaying widget(s)?

---

Here the code:

```
SudokuMarkerOverlayWidget::SudokuMarkerOverlayWidget(QWidget* parent, uint const fieldSize) : QWidget(parent)
{
    // Translucent should be the correct one
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TranslucentBackground);
    //setAttribute(Qt::WA_NoSystemBackground);
    setAttribute(Qt::WA_TransparentForMouseEvents);

    ...
}

void SudokuMarkerOverlayWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent*)
{
    QPainter painter(this);
    painter.setRenderHint( QPainter::Antialiasing );

    // Tried this too, no difference
    // painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Source);
    // painter.fillRect( this->rect(), Qt::transparent );
    painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_Clear);
    painter.eraseRect( this->rect() );
    painter.setCompositionMode(QPainter::CompositionMode_SourceOver);

    ...
}
```

EDIT:
Just noticed, using CompositionMode Source instead of SourceOver for my semi-transparent painting (gradient seen in first image) also causes them to be a red-to-black-gradient instead of red-to-transparent.

That means every transparency except the inital by `WA_TranslucentBackground` or `WA_NoSystemBackground` isn't working.

Comment: did you try to `Explicitly clear the old rectangle with a **transparent brush**` instead of erasing it (like it's said in the answer to the question you showed us)?

Comment: yeah i did, with composition mode source - no difference to using composition mode clear

Answer (score 0):

Widgets in Qt can be either a ['native' or 'alien' type](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html). In one case they're a separate operating system window. In some operating systems a transparent window isn't supported.

You might want to consider using QML if you're after fancy visual effects. That's what it was designed for.

Comment: ok, you might have a point, but still - there IS working transparency, just the clearing isn't working

Comment: my last comment seems worse then i meant it, of course if I don't get this to work without much expense I'll consider using alternatives

Comment: It might just be as simple as specifying a window flag on your constructor. I had quite the time making transparency work on windows and it wasn't very robust. No worries.